# Can i write to data output stream after reading response from data input stream?

Tags: java, java-me

i want to do a client-server activity like this:
1. first the client sends/writes to output stream
2. the server responses with some data that will be read with input stream
3. after receiving the data, the client sends/writes to output stream again to respond that the data has been received

now, do i have to close the output stream and re-open it again before doing step no.3 ?
also if someone could provide me with a snippet, it would be really helpful. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could if you want to, but you don't need to. However, you would need to `flush()` after writing to the `OutputStream` in case it is buffered.

The problem would be to know when to read. If the number of bytes to be read is available and performance is not an issue, you can use the blocking call `readFully`. But this is just one possible strategy.

Comment: thanks, but before i get to write to stream for the second time, i got RuntimeException Stream closed exception. i didn't do close()

Comment: I see from the other comment that you're doing HTTP connection. If so, it makes sense. The browsers will not use the same TCP link to send two different POSTs. So basically once the first HTTP connection is done, it will be closed by the client (causing the server to throw closed stream error when it tries to write to that connection). When the client is sending the second POST, another TCP link is started.

Comment: if so, do you have a solution to this. i'm really stuck, there's got to be the second POST request